# An owned file descriptor

Tags: c++, file, io

File descriptors are a common resource in Unix and Unix-like operating systems. They're a way to represent a resource such as a file, socket and so on.
The user should release a file descriptor as soon as (s)he's done with the corresponding resource: tipically they're limited to 1024 per process.

I implemented a RAII wrapper with some inspiration from the `std::unique_ptr` interface.

Usage example:

```
#include "FileDescriptor.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    FileDescriptor ownedFd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR) ;

    int fd = ownedFd.release();

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ownedFd.isValid() << "\n";

    ownedFd = FileDescriptor(fd);

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ownedFd.isValid() << "\n";

}
```

And the code:

### FileDescriptor.h

```
#ifndef FILEDESCRIPTOR_H
#define FILEDESCRIPTOR_H

#include <vector>

#include <cstdint>
#include <sys/select.h>

class FileDescriptor
{

public:
        FileDescriptor() = default;
        /*explicit*/ FileDescriptor ( int );

        FileDescriptor ( FileDescriptor&& ) noexcept ;
        FileDescriptor& operator=(FileDescriptor &&) noexcept ;

        virtual ~FileDescriptor();

    // Copy Assignment and Copy Constructor are implicitly deleted because of user-defined move semantics.

        void close();
        int release();
        int getFd();

        bool isValid() {
                return M_fd != invalid_fd;
        }


        static constexpr int invalid_fd = -1;

        enum Monitor : std::uint8_t {
                Read   = 1, // Read activity
                Write  = 2, // Write activity
                Except = 4  // Exceptional activity (such as incoming OOB data)
        };



        using fd_list = std::vector<FileDescriptor*>;   // pointers are needed for polymorphism: containers store objects,
                            // references are not.  §23.2.1 Standard C++

    // NOTE: Static member function or free function?
        static void select ( fd_list &, fd_list &, fd_list & ); 
        static void unique_select ( fd_list &, FileDescriptor::Monitor );

protected:
        int M_fd = invalid_fd; 

private:

        bool M_isValid ( int ); // check if a fd is actually valid, hence at kernel level.
        void M_tryClose();
        void M_do_close();

        static int M_create_set ( const fd_list&, fd_set & ); // Utility: populates the fd_set with the fds in the fd_list 
                                                              // and returns the highest element.

        static void M_remove_unset ( fd_list&, const fd_set & );

};

#endif // FILEDESCRIPTOR_H
```

### FileDescriptor.cpp

```
#include "FileDescriptor.h"

#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <stdexcept>
using std::invalid_argument;

#include <system_error>
using std::system_error;
using std::system_category;

#include <algorithm>
using std::max;
using std::max_element;
using std::remove_if;

#include <iostream>
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

#include <cerrno>

using std::vector;

FileDescriptor::FileDescriptor ( int fd ) // fd may either be an invalid_fd or an _actual_ fd
{

    if ( fd != this->invalid_fd  ) {
        if ( M_isValid(fd) )
            this->M_fd = fd;
        else
            throw invalid_argument ( "Invalid file descriptor" );
    }


}

FileDescriptor::FileDescriptor ( FileDescriptor&& fd ) noexcept : M_fd ( fd.M_fd )
{
        fd.M_fd = invalid_fd;
}

FileDescriptor& FileDescriptor::operator= ( FileDescriptor&& rhs ) noexcept 
{
        M_tryClose();

        this->M_fd = rhs.M_fd;
        rhs.M_fd = FileDescriptor::invalid_fd;


   return *this;
}


FileDescriptor::~FileDescriptor()
{
        M_tryClose();
}

void FileDescriptor::M_do_close()
{
       if ( ::close ( M_fd ) != 0 ) {

                M_fd = FileDescriptor::invalid_fd;
                throw system_error ( errno, system_category(), "Attempted to close an invalid file descriptor" );

        }


        M_fd = invalid_fd; // fd closed successfully; mark it as no longer valid
}

void FileDescriptor::close()
{
    M_tryClose();

}

void FileDescriptor::M_tryClose()
{

        if ( this->isValid() ) {

                try {
                        this->M_do_close();
                } catch ( system_error e ) {

                        // this should not happen: we thought the file descriptor as valid but close failed! 

                        cerr << "For some weird, unpredicted reason the file descriptor has turned out to be invalid."
                                "This should not happen. Please issue a bug report. \n"
                             << "Error encountered: " << e.what() << endl;


                }

        }



}


int FileDescriptor::release()
{
        int tmp_fd = M_fd;
        M_fd = invalid_fd;

        return tmp_fd;
}

int FileDescriptor::getFd()
{
        return M_fd;
}


bool FileDescriptor::M_isValid ( int fd )
{
        return fcntl ( fd, F_GETFL ) != -1; // is the fd _actually_ valid? Only the kernel can provide this information.
}


int FileDescriptor::M_create_set ( const fd_list& v, fd_set& empty_set )
{
        int max_fd = invalid_fd;

        for ( const auto&i : v ) {
                FD_SET ( i->M_fd, &empty_set );
                max_fd = max ( max_fd, i->M_fd );
        }

        return max_fd;
}

void FileDescriptor::M_remove_unset ( fd_list& v, const fd_set& set_fds )
{
        v.erase ( remove_if( v.begin(), v.end(), [&] ( FileDescriptor *fd ) { return !FD_ISSET ( fd->M_fd, &set_fds ); } ), v.end() );
}


void FileDescriptor::unique_select ( fd_list& unique_list, Monitor mode )
{
        fd_set list_set;
        FD_ZERO ( &list_set );

        int max_fd = M_create_set ( unique_list, list_set );

        int rc = ::select ( max_fd + 1, ( mode & Monitor::Read ? &list_set : nullptr ),
                        ( mode & Monitor::Write ? &list_set : nullptr ),
                    ( mode & Monitor::Except ? &list_set : nullptr ), nullptr );

        if ( rc == -1 )
                throw system_error ( errno, system_category(), "Could not select" );

        M_remove_unset ( unique_list, list_set );

}


void FileDescriptor::select ( fd_list& readList, fd_list& writeList, fd_list& exceptList )
{
        fd_set readSet, writeSet, exceptSet;

        FD_ZERO ( &readSet );
        exceptSet = writeSet = readSet;

        auto ilist = { M_create_set ( readList, readSet ), M_create_set ( writeList, writeSet ), M_create_set ( exceptList, exceptSet ), FileDescriptor::invalid_fd };

        int max_fd = *max_element ( ilist.begin(), ilist.end() );

        if ( max_fd == invalid_fd )
                throw invalid_argument ( "No file descriptor provided." );

        // We now have the highest file descriptor and the fd_sets set up: we can select.

        int rc = ::select ( max_fd + 1, &readSet, &writeSet, &exceptSet, nullptr ); // TODO: Check the effect of void fd_sets in fs/select.c

        if ( rc == -1 )
                throw system_error ( errno, system_category(), "Could not select" );


        // select was successful: we'll remove unset fds.
        M_remove_unset ( readList, readSet );
        M_remove_unset ( writeList, writeSet );
        M_remove_unset ( exceptList, exceptSet );


}
```

My worries:

1. Should `select` and `unique_select` be static member functions or global ones?
2. Should `FileDescriptor(int)` be `explicit`? I can find motivations for it to both be and not to be.
3. Usability
4. Efficiency (with particular regard to `select`/`unique_select`)

Any other suggestion will be also appreciated.

### Inheritance explainations

This class is inherited from other classes to "specialize" a file descriptor: as said before, a file descriptor can be a socket, file and so on.
When you want to `select`, you select on fds but they might be a Socket for instance: hence the polymorphism. I had an hard time to go for inheritance: because a socket, for example, is *represented* by a fd thus composition and inheritance *would* be excluded but inheritance at the end seemed to fit better. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a Unix guy so some of these points may reflect my ignorance!

I'm a little puzzled what business your `select` / `unique_select` functions or indeed the `fd_list` alias have as part of the `FileDescriptor` class. This seems to violate the Single Responsibility Principle. To me, the `FileDescriptor` class should be purely about managing the lifetime of the file descriptor and nothing more. If you want utility functions like `select` they should not be part of the `FileDescriptor` class.

A related point: it doesn't seem very idiomatic C++ to make a specific container a part of the interface for `select`. It would be more idiomatic to take a pair of templated iterators so you could work with any container.

I'm also unclear why your `fd_list` holds `FileDescriptors` by pointer. It's not clear from the code here what the use of polymorphism would be for a `FileDescriptor`. In general RAII types are inherently value types and so a polymorphic RAII type doesn't make much sense to me.

Finally, I would think you would want to provide a constructor that takes the arguments to `open` and performs the open, or a utility function similar to `make_unique()` that does the same. This way you never have to have raw / unowned `int` file descriptors floating around.

Comment: Hello @mattnewport. 
`select`ing seems to me like an operation you do *on* fds but I'm uncertain to make them free functions.
Yes, `unique_select` can definitely accept a pair of iterators. I wouldn't say the same for `select`, would you?

Comment: I've edited and given motivations for `FileDescriptor*`. 
I also like an `open` method and constructor with such parameters.

Comment: I still think there's a problem with the use of inheritance here. It conflates the resource ownership responsibilities of the `FileDescriptor` with the polymorphic use of different types of fd. If you really need polymorphic fd types, I think you should separate them out from the RAII class that manages their lifetimes, otherwise once you start passing `FileDescriptor` pointers around you now have a lifetime management problem for those!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this implementation actually counts as RAII, as you can initialize your `FileDescriptor` in an "invalid" state. Why? Either you have an object, and an open file, or you don't, and no open file. Thus in my opinion there should be no default constructor and no `is_valid()` method.

If you want a variable for holding a file descriptor, but which you don't want initialized just yet - use an `std::optional<>` around a proper RAII wrapper (or an `std::future` in some rare cases where that's relevant).

Comment: I see what you mean, however there are countless examples of C++ classes considered as being RAII which follow this pattern: std::file, std::shared_ptr and so on... Having an "uninitialized" or "unallocated" state of a supposedly RAII object is unfortunate but often unavoidable, especially when the object is a wrapper of a non-OOP object.

Comment: @Wizard79: That's a valid point. I would say that this is mostly due to how, unfortunately, we don't have move destructors in C++. Right now, in order to allow for moving, say, a unique pointer or a file, we must still keep the original object in a language-valid state - though not let it actually be associated with any resource, i.e. make it unusable. The other alternative to this compromise is not to allow moving, and keeping such variables strictly within-scope. So, a tradeoff between usability and conceptual purity.